# Edit row of table values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, row, edit

I have a table being created in Javascript via an input table on my html page. I added a delete and edit button on the Javascript table so when it returns values, these two buttons appear at the end of each row added. However,  I cannot get any sort of edit button at all. I have looked everywhere. Can anyone help me? 
I have a jsFiddle of my entire program.

http://jsfiddle.net/aabbey0411/c46d9n2e/

This is where I created the button:

```
   /**
 * This function returns a row of an HTML table containing the contact data.
 */
Contact.prototype.tableRow = function() {
    var deleteButton = "<button id ='delete'  onclick= 'deleteRow(this)'>Delete</button>"
    var editButton = "<button id ='edit'  onclick='editRow(this)'>Edit</button>"
    var tr = "</td><td>" + this.forename + "</td><td>" + this.surname + "</td><td>" + this.category + "</td><td>" + this.dob + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + this.marital_status + "</td><td>" + this.phone + "</td><td>" + this.email + "</td><td>" + this.address + "</td>" +
        "<td>" + this.postcode + "</td><td>" + this.notes + "</td>"  +
        "<td>" + editButton + "</td>" + "<td> " + deleteButton + "</td></tr>";

    return tr;


};


/* This function builds the HTML table, using the input of contact details
     */
    var updateList = function () {
        var tableDiv = document.getElementById("table"),
            table = "<table border='1'><thead><th>Forename</th><th>Surname</th><th>Category</th><th>Date of Birth</th>" +
               "<th>Status</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Email Address</th><th>Address</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Notes</th></thead>";

        for (var i = 0, j = contacts.length; i < j; i++) {
            var cont = contacts[i];
            table+= cont.tableRow();
        }

        table+= "</table>";
        tableDiv.innerHTML = table;


    };

 var showTable = function () {
        var tableDiv = document.getElementById("table"),
            table = "<table border='1'><thead><th>Forename</th><th>Surname</th><th>Category</th><th>Date of Birth</th><th>Status</th><th>Phone Number</th>" +
                "<th>Email Address</th><th>Address</th><th>Postcode</th><th>Notes</th><th>Delete</th></thead>";

        for(var i=0, j=contacts.length; i<j; i++){
            var cont = contacts[i];
            table += cont.tableRow();
        }
        table+="</table>";
        tableDiv.innerTML = table;
    };
```

Comment: I can't see the table in the fiddle.

Comment: @MoshFeu you have to input details first or just hit okay and then load contacts to get the table to load at the bottom

Comment: I tried to (in the fiddle) but it doesn't work.. (There are errors there about missing files - (`contactBook.css` and `contactForm.js`)

Comment: @MoshFeu i dont knoow then because i added my css and js file to the fiddle

Comment: When you click the `ok` button do you see the `table`?! Maybe you can delete the `form` and just show the table.

Comment: @MoshFeu it's not working for me on jsfiddle but when i use it on my internet alone with my own links its working

Comment: So, how can we help you? We need a **working** fiddle. Take my advice, create a fiddle with **just** the `table`.

Comment: @MoshFeu but you need the html table in order to load the javascript table that we cannot see and the load button clearly isnt working. can you not see my javascript code?

Comment: I can, but it's tool a long time to understand it without the full picture. That's why we are asking a fiddle.